# WooCommerce breadcrumbs doesn't show root category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On my site I have a section called "Shop" which is the root for my WooCommerce store.
When I open that section the rootnav shows:
You are here: Home / Shop

But then, if I open category it will update to:
You are here: Home / Wetsuits

And in a product view:
You are here: Home / Wetsuits / Sapatos Specialized GF35443

So it seems it's stripping the main section from the breadcrumbs.
Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Breadcrumbs root seems to be derived from permalinks. To change them, go to :

Settings > Permalinks > Product Permalinks

and set **Shop base**. After such change, you will see Home / Shop / Wetsuits in the breadcrumbs of category.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_home_url', 'woo_custom_breadrumb_home_url' );
function woo_custom_breadrumb_home_url() {
    return 'http://woothemes.com';
}
```

Comment: This changes the URL of Home but still keeps the Shop excluded from product view. I think OP wants to be in Home / Shop / Wetsuits